# D3 Zoom Settings

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, event-handling

I am having some trouble understanding how zoom work in D3, specifically how it is called and the settings initialized. I have the following snippet of code (only the essential bits are included), which is from a Manning Textbook on D3 V4 and works fine:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height)

function createMap(countries, cities) {
    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(scale)
        .translate([width/2,height/2])

var mapZoom = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomed)

var zoomSettings = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(width/2, height/2)
    .scale(scale)

svg.call(mapZoom).call(mapZoom.transform, zoomSettings) // ?!!!

function zoomed() {
        var e = d3.event
        .translate([e.transform.x, e.transform.y])
        .scale(e.transform.k)

    // I didn't include the drawing of the paths, but 
       they are appended to the SVG, and this updates their data.

    d3.selectAll("path.graticule").attr("d", geoPath)
    d3.selectAll("path.countries").attr("d", geoPath)
    d3.selectAll("circle.cities")
    .attr("cx", d => projection([d.x,d.y])[0])
    .attr("cy", d => projection([d.x,d.y])[1])
}
```

**Why is it necessary to call the zoom function multiple times on the svg?** **The first time it is called, we don't pass it the "zoomSettings", and the second time we do. What is the point of this?** Does it have something to do with the fact that the zoom event is working on the SVG, rather than a group holding all of my paths? I'm used to much more simple examples of zoom like this, which are called on an SVG and the elements are bound to a Group:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1,3])
    .on("zoom", zoomed)

function zoomed(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height)
    .call(zoom)

var g = d3.select("svg").append("g")

// All elements are bound to group^
```

Any clarification someone could provide on this would be greatly appreciated. I find the zoom() in D3 to be incredibly confusing, despite the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
svg.call(mapZoom).call(mapZoom.transform, zoomSettings)
```

is doing two separate things.

First, `svg.call(mapZoom)` is [applying the zoom behavior](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#_zoom) to the `svg`.  The second call, `.call(mapZoom.transform, zoomSettings)`, is [programmatically setting a zoom transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform) to the svg.  This is setting it's initial state before the user does anything to it.

So think about it like this:

1. Create the zoom behavior (`var zoom = d3.zoom()`)
2. Apply it to svg element (`svg.call(mapZoom)`)
3. Set its initial state (`.call(mapZoom.transform, zoomSettings)`)